# Google map wont work from IFRAME

Tags: php, google-maps, iframe, smarty

I need to generate map from address (string)

the string itself:

```
1072 Budapest Rákóczi út 12.
```

this is how I put it to the site:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.hu/maps?q={$infos.address|escape:'url'}"></iframe>
```

and this is the final output:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.hu/maps?q=1072%20Budapest%20R%C3%A1k%C3%B3czi%20%C3%BAt%2012." marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

and that is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameter `output=embed` to the URL.

This parameter will force google to send an appropriate `X-Frame-Options`-header